# Regex with a long search pattern which has tabs and newline characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a page http://www.codesend.com/view/ef460e9fc2346099e040843c6c4d8631/. I load the html of the page in my program. I need to get these (.*?) patterns values but when I try it with regex in C# it doesn't work. I think it's a problem with tabs or newline characters.

Comment: Can you add some of the code you're using, so we can see what might be going wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you sure, that you want to use Regexes to parse HTML (which is generally a bad decision)?

Comment: -1:whats is (.*?)!Are u representing it as a pattern or content

Comment: Agree with Bismark about using regexes to parse HTML. If you are set on doing it though please post the regex that doesn't work so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a problem with newline characters, have you tried to set the Singleline Regex option?

```
Regex regex = new Regex(yourpattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

(.*?) is a regex-group/pattern, that is basically saying: give 0 or more characters (except newline) in a non-greedy fashion. Non-greedy means it gives you the shortest possible result, which is - nothing.

Here is a good cheat-sheet of the regex syntax:
http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

And here is a good website to test your regular expressions:
http://regexpal.com/